# Error when printing crystal report , Index and length must refer to a location within the string. Parameter name: length

Tags: crystal-reports

When I try to print my crystal report this error shows up:

> Index and length must refer to a location within the string. Parameter
>   name: length

[image]

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: Probably there's a function inside a formula that attempts to take a substring of a string, but the string-value is to short or `NULL`. The function may be `MID` for example.

Comment: thanks for the reply ! yet the problem is that i don't even have one line of code , it just views the data that i have from an already made procedure !

Comment: It is not possible to advice without knowing the code, that caused the error